# SwiftUI SecureField Keep Track of Active/Inactive State

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, swiftui

I need to keep track of whether a SecureField is active or not (ie showing the keyboard)

For a regular TextField I use onEditingChanged which provides me a boolean if its active or inactive

SecureField does not have this method though. How can I keep track of the active state?

Comment: Well... this is an ugly hack, but if you have a single SecureField in your view, you could listen to the keyBoardWillShow notification and keep track of all your other TextFields. If none has been activated (onEditingChanged), then it must be your Securefield. Terrible, I know. I think it would be a good idea to report it as a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately even that hack won't work for me because my view will have 2 SecureFields on it: enter password & confirm password

Comment: This is still not a solution, but did you know you can hook a closure to every character typed in the securefield, by using Combine: if myvar is the @State/@Binding variable you use with the SecureField, you can do: myvar.publisher().sink { c in print("character: \(c)") }. Unfortunately the publisher does nothing when the field gets activated. But at least you can know which one was the last field used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for now. SwiftUI still in development phase and this event handler doesn't exist for SecureField for now.

I was encountered this problem recently, I make all labels as a State variable and control like this

```
Text(username != "" ? usernamePlaceholder:" ").font(.subheadline)
```